# Async Check for UDP port open

Tags: wpf, vb.net, asynchronous, port, udpclient

I have this snippet, I just wonder which is the best way to have it async, so it is not going to hang my UI. Have it as Task.run the whole bit, or is there an async version of these connections?

```
    Private Function CheckUDPPortOpen(Address As String, Port As Integer)
    Try
        Dim udpClient As UdpClient = New UdpClient()
        Dim uSocket As Socket = udpClient.Client
        uSocket.ReceiveTimeout = 3000
        uSocket.Connect(Address, Port)
        udpClient.Connect(Address, Port)
        Dim RemoteIpEndPoint As IPEndPoint = CreateIPEndPoint(Address & ":" & Port)
        Dim sendBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("?")
        udpClient.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length)
        Dim receiveBytes As Byte() = udpClient.Receive(RemoteIpEndPoint)
       Catch e As SocketException

        If e.ErrorCode = 10054 Then
            Return "Port is closed"
        Else
            Return "Port not reachable"
        End If
    End Try

    Return "Port is working fine"
End Function
```

The RemoteIPEndPoint function:

```
        Public Shared Function CreateIPEndPoint(ByVal endPoint As String) As IPEndPoint
    Dim ep As String() = endPoint.Split(":"c)
    If ep.Length <> 2 Then Throw New FormatException("Invalid endpoint format")
    Dim ip As IPAddress

    If Not IPAddress.TryParse(ep(0), ip) Then
        Throw New FormatException("Invalid ip-adress")
    End If

    Dim port As Integer

    If Not Integer.TryParse(ep(1), NumberStyles.None, NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo, port) Then
        Throw New FormatException("Invalid port")
    End If

    Return New IPEndPoint(ip, port)
End Function
```

Comment: [UdpClient.ReceiveAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient.receiveasync) -- [UdpClient.SendAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient.sendasync)

Comment: Can you please change my code, I've tried it, but having issues with receiveasync.

Comment: It would be better for you to post your broken code and we can help and educate you how to do it right. If we just do it for you then you won't learn as much; there is a great value in looking at a student's failed attempts, because working out how they perceive a problem is the key to helping them solve it